# Center two side by side minipages in table

Tags: tables

This is what I have:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|| c || c | c | c | c ||}
      \hline
      $a_0$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_1$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_2$ & & & &\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|| c || c | c | c | c ||}
      \hline
      $a_0$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_1$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_2$ & & & &\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Tables are side by side but they are taken together and aligned to the left margin.

Is there a way to center my two tables together while still using only standard tables and minipages? I tried to put them both in a centered box but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you want to center each tabular in its minipage or do you want to center the two minipages inside of the table environment?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, how your tables should be placed on page. Probably as follows:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

For above result you only need to add `\centering` after each `\begin{minipage}{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering    % <---
    \begin{tabular}{|| c || c | c | c | c ||}
      \hline
      $a_0$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_1$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_2$ & & & &\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering    % <---
    \begin{tabular}{|| c || c | c | c | c ||}
      \hline
      $a_0$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_1$ & & & &\\
      \hline
      $a_2$ & & & &\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: the width of each table should be smaller than width of `minipage`.